# Реклама/Cсылки на сайте по полезным и качественным курсам участников стАкОверФлоу

Tags: предложение

задала на англоязычном сайте вопрос несколько дней назад по syncfusion (не суть) и мое внимание **привлекла реклама курсов боковой панели.**

[image: stack_pub]

по моему это очень хорошая идея, и стоило бы внедрить, таким образом например если еще бы **иконка участника этих курсов,** то тем кому он помог в ответах с удовольствием перейдут и посмотрят/купят/порекомендуют его курсы. *Приведу пример (думаю многие согласятся), если будет написано например онлайн курсы/блог/видео/статья @Akina  по SQL многие перейдут и таких много здесь знатоков, которые помогли своими ответами.*

Я уже задавала вопрос ни раз, видимо не так понят был, но думаю стоит **бриллианты** вывести в свет, а не прятать из вредности, что мол реклама запрещена, а другая сторона скажет ой дорого платить за рекламу (я не знаю всю кухню там как устроенно, но видно же англоязычные сайты ставят ссылки (и это не что то там популярное типа Юдеми,есть одна ссылка на них только, там какое то все новое незнакомое. **продвигают и правильно**) я зашла, мало что поняла (за незнанием языка) и таких как я не мало здесь => доказательство, что вопросы и участие на русскомСтакОверФлоу живут). *Еще один пример, если будут где то готовые веб наброски наших отвечающих css, то пользователи зайдут приобретут. Да и много чего.* *Например тот же кодеРевью*

Участникам если предоставить условия (может слишком строго/дорого/муторно там все или наоборт вообще никак), они с удовольствием отправят свои ссылки/курсы/и прочее и кстати даже начнут больше отвечать, чтоб создать себе какое своего рода портфолио. А начинающим будет где знания черпать. Не понимаю почему запрещать показывать работы участников `Ru.stackOverFlow`

Гугл вообще перестает все больше и больше русскоязычные сайты давать в рекомендациях/поиске, я живу в Европе и порой приходится пройти на вторую третью страницу, чтоб найти русскоязычный интересный контент/курс/статью/

Панель боковая тут всегда лысая => примите к сведению

Comment: В чем суть предложения то? Добавить на сайт такую же рекламу? Или разрешить просто в ответах рекламировать курсы?

Comment: в идеале как у EnStackOverflow сделать (да, добавить рекламу/ссылки итп). Участник задал вопрос (не тут а, а на основном сайте, где технические вопросы) и как задал вопрос сбоку выходит баннер и мигает, типа вот это может вас заинтересовать. А так изначально просто хоть колонку выделить под всякое что относится к участникам (их проекты, и тому подобное, чем они захотят поделиться, кстати возможно это есть, но никто не делится, так значит смягчить условия чтоли)

Comment: про рекламу курсов в ответах почему вообще это запрещать не понимаю(я даже не задумывалась, а эта идея тоже класс, типа спросил кто что то, а ему хоп и вот ссылочка...). Программирование это же не бренд какой то, чтоб прям такая борьба шла. У каждых курсов найдется свой потребитель. Если курс плохой ему хоть рекламу сделай никто не будет смотреть, если комменты отпишут, ну или пару раз посмотрят горе учителя.

Comment: "Программирование это же не бренд какой то, чтоб прям такая борьба шла." - Святая простота. Когда в ящике с известными актерами рекламируют IT-курсы, что это, как не борьба брендов за рынок?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я считаю, это не нужно. Реклама отвлекает от основного содержания сайта, и есть лишь небольшой шанс, что рекламируемые курсы будут интересны зашедшему на сайт участнику. Те, кто ищут курсы по IT, найдут их в другом месте, недостатка в них нет. Реклама в первую очередь выгодна продавцу для увеличения продаж, поэтому нам не нужно что-то специально делать ради увеличения количества рекламы. Когда надо будет, она сама придет.

> по моему это очень хорошая идея, и стоило бы внедрить, таким образом например если еще бы иконка участника этих курсов, то тем кому он помог в ответах с удовольствием перейдут и посмотрят/купят/порекомендуют его курсы.

Тогда организаторы курсов будут специально набивать репутацию, чтобы привлечь больше внимания к своим курсам. Как идея для повышения доходов владельцев сайта, может быть хорошая, а вот эффект на качестве ответов будет скорее отрицательный.

> Гугл вообще перестает все больше и больше русскоязычные сайты давать в рекомендациях/поиске, я живу в Европе и порой приходится пройти на вторую третью страницу, чтоб найти русскоязычный интересный контент/курс/статью/

Это проблема гугла, или проблема Европы. Или, что более вероятно, вы забыли выставить в настройках браузера предпочитаемый язык. Поисковые системы часто ориентируются именно на него, а не на язык запроса. Так или иначе, в цели Stackoverflow на русском не входит помогать участникам в поиске ресурсов в интернете.

> Панель боковая тут всегда лысая => примите к сведению

Панель выглядит так, как и должна выглядеть. Если вы намекаете на отсутствие рекламы, она раньше была, но куда-то исчезла. Даже баннеров с улыбающимся Николасом, призывающих задавать вопросы, теперь не видно. Куда подевалась - интересный вопрос, но я не думаю, что кто-то по ней скучает.

Comment: [Всё там же](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E81ly.jpg).